# Generating JSON out put using two separate list with Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Java and have two list, one have field names and other have values. I am generating JSON using list values and it is working fine as shown below.

```
String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().
                        create().toJson(fieldValues );
                fileOut.println(json);
```

Repetitive field values are coming like this:

```
  [
    "2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z",
   "sensor_2000:,
    "10",
    1.0
  ],
  [
    "2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z",
    "sensor_1000:,
    "20",
    2.0
  ],
```

Now i have another small constant field list having field names in it, which have contents as shown below:

```
[
  "time",
  "sensor",
  "sequence_number",
  "component_id"
]
```

How can i merge columns names list with the first list having values, and get the out put like this:

```
 [
       "time":"2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z",
       "sensor":"sensor_2000:,
       "sequence_number":"10",
       "component_id":1.0
      ],
      [
        "time":"2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z",
        "sensor":"sensor_1000:,
        "sequence_number":"20",
        "component_id":2.0
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have 2 lists: one with the values and the other one with the names.

Values:

```
[["2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z","sensor_2000:",10,1.0],["2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z","sensor_1000:",20,2.0]]
```

Names:

```
[time, sensor, sequence_number, component_id]
```

You can use the **JsonObject** in order to achieve your goal. In particular [the addProperty method](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#addProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Here is it the example:

```
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        List<Object> finalValue= new LinkedList<>();
        List<Object> value= new LinkedList<>();
        List<Object> value2= new LinkedList<>();
        List<String> names= new LinkedList<>();

        value.add("2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z");
        value.add("sensor_2000:");
        value.add(10);
        value.add(1.0);

        value2.add("2017-10-02T21:06:08.134061801Z");
        value2.add("sensor_1000:");
        value2.add(20);
        value2.add(2.0);

        finalValue.add(value);
        finalValue.add(value2);

        names.add("time");
        names.add("sensor");
        names.add("sequence_number");
        names.add("component_id");

        System.out.println("values: " + gson.toJson(finalValue));
        System.out.println("names: " + names);


        LinkedList<JsonObject> finalList= new LinkedList<>();

        for(Object obj: finalValue)
        {
            JsonObject jsonObj= new JsonObject();
            List<Object> valueObj = (List<Object>) obj;
            int i=0;
            for(Object innerObj: valueObj)
            {
                if(names.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("component_id"))
                {
                    jsonObj.addProperty(names.get(i), Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(innerObj))) ;
                }
                else if(names.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("sequence_number"))
                {
                jsonObj.addProperty(names.get(i), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(innerObj))) ;
                }
                else {
                    jsonObj.addProperty(names.get(i), String.valueOf(innerObj)) ;
                }
                i++;
            }

            finalList.add(jsonObj);
        }

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(finalList));

    }
```